# airflow log_format use logging_mixin.py as the source file instead of the real source file

Tags: airflow

airflow default `log_format` is:

```
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
```

This format create logs like this:

```
[2021-06-21 10:19:19,684] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - this print is from python file
```

The `filename` should be the name of the file that print this log but instead of printing the real file (for example my_file.py) airflow use `logging_mixin.py` as the source file of **all** log lines that the user insert in his files.

How can I config airflow so he will print the real source file of the log line?

In the example above I want to get:

```
[2021-06-21 10:19:19,684] {my_file.py:104} INFO - this print is from python file
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using LoggingMixin wrongly. This is a Mixin so it should be inherited by your class.

You should implement multiple-inheritance pattern and have your class inherit from LoggingMixin.

for example (from Airflow codebase):

```
class DagFileProcessorProcess(AbstractDagFileProcessorProcess, LoggingMixin, MultiprocessingStartMethodMixin):
```

What I suspect you are instantiating like that:

```
logging=LoggingMixin()
```

and use `logging.log()` or similar.

In Airflow 1.10 it was used sometimes like that (wrongly) but in Airflow 2 it's been corrected everywhere.